# where to store custom templates in Android studio 4.1 or above

Tags: android, android-studio

In latest Android studio, there is no templates folder in libs folder `/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/other/`

Where custom templates can be saved. Is there any change post 3.6+